# Rails link_to_add_fields with jquery Mobile not rendering the layout

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile for markup, and I notice that link_to_add_fields in application_helper.rb doesn't convert the rendering to jquery mobile style. It makes sense, JQuery Mobile would mark up the things with its framework before rendering it to the browser. However, is there a way to get around this problem and render it on server side?

Code:-

```
_certification.html.erb
<fieldset>   
  <%= f.input :certification,:input_html=>{:class=>"string optional ui-input-text ui-body-d"} %>
     <%= link_to('#', class: "label label-inverse") do%>Remove<i class="remove-icon"></i><% end %>       
</fieldset>

_form.html.erb
 <%= f.simple_fields_for :certifications do |ed|%>
          <%= render "certifications", f: ed %>
      <% end %>  
 <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Achievement", f, :certifications,'user' %>

application_helper.rb

 def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association,controller= "")
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.simple_fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(controller.to_s + '/' + association.to_s, f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "btn btn-inverse", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did link_to_add_fields come from? It's not standard rails or jquery, IIRC.   It sounds like something out of a railscast, which isn't necessarily designed with jquery_mobile in mind.

*edit*
You have to notify jquery mobile of the changes so it can repaint the page. See http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html in the section "Enhancing new markup"

**Enhancing new markup**

The page plugin dispatches a pageInit event, which most widgets use to auto-initialize themselves. As long as a widget plugin script is referenced, it will automatically enhance any instances of the widgets it finds on the page.

However, if you generate new markup client-side or load in content via Ajax and inject it into a page, you can trigger the create event to handle the auto-initialization for all the plugins contained within the new markup. This can be triggered on any element (even the page div itself), saving you the task of manually initializing each plugin (listview button, select, etc.).

For example, if a block of HTML markup (say a login form) was loaded in through Ajax, trigger the create event to automatically transform all the widgets it contains (inputs and buttons in this case) into the enhanced versions. The code for this scenario would be:

```
$( ...new markup that contains widgets... ).appendTo( ".ui-page" ).trigger( "create" );
```

Comment: link_to_add_fields is a helper method which I have refereed from Railscast. But how we can change the helper method to make it supports Jquery mobile